# How do I determine the collation of a database in SQL 2005?

Tags: sql, collation

How do you determine the collation of a database in SQL 2005, for instance if you need to perform a case-insensitive search/replace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following SQL determines the collation of a database:

```
SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX('{database name}', 'Collation') SQLCollation;
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember, that individual columns can override the database collation:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, COLLATION_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do a case-insensitive search and can't rely on the database's collation, you could always specifically request it for the query you're interested in.  For instance:

```
SELECT TOP 1 FName, *
FROM People
WHERE FName LIKE '%mich%' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI
```

I usually have the opposite problem, where I want the case sensitivity but don't have it in the database's collation, so I find myself using the Latin1_General_BIN collation quite a bit in my queries.  If you don't already know, you can do:

```
SELECT 
FROM ::fn_helpcollations()
```

for a list of the available collations and descriptions of what they're for.

Answer (score 1):

Select the Database and run the following command.

```
sp_helpsort
```